# Is there a Open Source or Shareware Legal Move Checker Executable?

Tags: software

**Background:**  I wrote and use a custom macro in the NoteTab Pro text editor to convert PGN position analysis to XML.  The resulting XML is used on my website to display chess puzzles.  I need to check for legal moves in some cases.  For example, a PGN move might say Rd6 in a position where two rooks can move to d6, but only one of them can legally move to d6 because the other is pinned to its King.  I am disinclined to write a macro legal move checker due to the apparent complexity of the task.  I do not want to reinvent the wheel.

Ideally, I am looking for an executable that can be called with FEN and next-move parameters, and return a positive or negative result based on the move's legality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple problem. `python-chess` is a useful Python package that can do it for you easily. You will need to get a FEN, check if your move is a legal move.

> https://pypi.org/project/python-chess/

has everything you want.

Comment: Hmmm...  It will take me some time to digest Python-Chess.  I don't speak Python.  I am not sure what a package is, or what this specific package can do.  Do you know of any tutorial to get a novice started with Python and this package?  Until then I will take your word for it and accept your answer.  Thanks.